# Resource not found error when using TForm as base for a component

Tags: delphi

I am writing a component and want to change the base type to a TForm however at run time I get the error "Resource TMyComp not found".  I guess that this is because there is no dfm but I am not sure what to do about it.

Thanks

```
unit Unit65;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TMyComp = class(TForm);

  TForm65 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    Mc: TMyComp;
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form65: TForm65;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm65.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Mc := TMyComp.Create(Self);
  Mc.Parent := nil;
  Mc.ShowModal;
end;

end.
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at Delphi Custom Containers Pack https://sourceforge.net/projects/ccpack/

Answer (score 13):

There is no .dfm file for `TMyComp`. You can avoid attempting to load the .dfm by calling the [`CreateNew`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.CreateNew) constructor rather than `Create`.

```
Mc := TMyComp.CreateNew(Self);
```

From the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.CreateNew):

> Use CreateNew instead of Create to create a form without using the
>   associated .DFM file to initialize it. Always use CreateNew if the
>   TCustomForm descendant is not a TForm object or a descendant of TForm.
>
> CreateNew bypasses the streaming in of the previously-associated .DFM
>   file. If the form contains visual components, therefore, you must
>   stream in an external .DFM to bind the visual components with their
>   classes. If the newly created form has an external .DFM file, then you
>   can follow the call to CreateNew with a call to
>   InitInheritedComponent. If you need to create the .dfm file for the
>   new form instance, bracket the call to CreateNew with calls to
>   WriteComponentResFile and ReadComponentResFile.