# FormCreate procedure

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I have two units in my project as follow:

1 - Connexion unit:

```
unit Connexion;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TFConn = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Déclarations privées }
  public
    { Déclarations publiques }
  end;

var
  FConn: TFConn;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses MainForm;

procedure TFConn.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not Assigned(FMain) then
    begin
      FMain := TFMain.CreateNew(Application);
      FMain.OnClose := FMain.FormClose;
      FMain.ShowModal;
    end;
end;

end.
```

2 - MainForm unit :

```
unit MainForm;

interface
   uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TFMain = class(TForm)
     Constructor  FormCreate(Sender: TObject);overload;
     procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  end;
Var
  FMain : TFMain;
implementation

Constructor  TFMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var B :  TButton;
begin
   inherited;
   B := TButton.Create(Self);
   B.Parent := Self;
   B.Caption := 'Button2';
end;

procedure tfmain.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  FMain := Nil;
end;
end.
```

The problem is that the procedure `FormCreate` in MainForm unit not working , I know that I miss something in the declaration , because the procedure should fire while the creation of the `FMain` form .

The application run without any error , but it should create `B` button on the `FMain` form.

How can I do that?

Comment: This is a mix of something I can't make sense of (if `tfmain` is a main form, why do create it from a non main one?). Well, as first I would get rid of the global variables.

Comment: @Victoria `MainForm` is not the main form of the application , Connexion is the main form of the application as you can see .

Comment: So why did you choose such a name? Won't that confuse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Constructor  FormCreate(Sender: TObject);overload;
```

is wrong. It should be:

```
procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
```

The other problem is that you must set the `OnCreate` event to refer to `FormCreate`. Do this in the events page of the object inspector.

That will also need you to have a dfm file for this form which you appear not to have. Once you restore the dfm file you can set the `OnClose` event handler in the same way. You'd need to switch to `Create` rather than `CreateNew`.

You can't set the `OnCreate` event handler in code because the form has already been created.

If there is a good reason not to have a dfm file and do everything in code then you could need to add a constructor. Do that by overriding the virtual constructor:

```
constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
```

Finally, very much of the code in the question looks dubious, shall I saw. Strange use of global variables. Odd naming. Setting important events like `OnClose` from outside the class. Testing against nil that suggests weak design. I think there are problems ahead.

Comment: Can I do that wothout a `DFM` file of the `MainForm` unit?

Comment: I think it's all explained in the answer, no?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Comment: `TObject` or `TComponent` , because I try what you say and also fail

Comment: Well I did the same way you say , `constructor Create(AOwner: TObject); override;` but I think there is a wrong with the type `TObject`

Comment: OK, I see, that should be TComponent

Comment: Yeah , That's it , Now the app run fine ,there is only one error about the dfm , because when I click the button to create the form I got an error msg about the resource (dfm) . You know where you can find me to discuss about this for 1 mn please.

Comment: You need to fix your attitude. You come back here, unaccept the answer, and expect me to debug a program I cannot see, providing me with nothing more than "I got an error message about the resource". Are you serious? That's the best you can do. No code and you can't even manage to transcribe the error message. Usually people that don't transcribe error messages are the same people that don't even read them and attempt to understand them. Are you that person? This is a question and answer site. I answered the question. If you don't agree fine.

Comment: I get the same error in that question https://stackoverflow.com/q/41889732/6426692 , and your answer was _Use `CreateNew`_ , But I want to use `Create` instead without a dfm. hope that I describe well.

Comment: If you derive directly from `TForm` then I think you can get away with it, but why are you making life so hard. Add a .dfm. It doesn't need to have anything in it. You can still create controls dynamically. No point fighting the system.